# Python for loop isn't working. (Pygame, Pycharm)

Tags: python, for-loop, pygame, pycharm

I'm new to programming and I'm currently writing a game using pygame and pycharm.

I need to scale some images down from their original size and I can get it just fine by typing them all out 1 at a time but when I try and shorten the code using a for loop it doesn't work.

```
    numbers = [num0_img, num1_img, etc...]
    for image in numbers:
        image = scale(image, (15, 15))
```

Doesn't scale the images down. But typing it all out works.

```
    num0_img = scale(num0_img, (15, 15))
    num1_img = scale(num1_img, (15, 15))
    etc...
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Also just a note. I have imported it correctly.

```
    import pygame
    from pygame.transform import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for-loop is just repeatedly reassigning the name `image` to `scale(image, (15, 15))`.  It never affects the objects stored in `numbers`.  Below is a demonstration

```
>>> lst = [[1], [2]]
>>> for i in lst:
...     i = [3]
...
>>> lst
[[1], [2]]
>>> i
[3]
>>>
```

To fix the problem, you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and mutate `numbers` in-place:

```
numbers[:] = [scale(image, (15, 15)) for image in numbers]
```

Comment: Assigning to `numbers` would be enough, no need to mutate the original list.

Comment: Sure, you could do that if you want.  It looked like the OP wanted to preserve the original list object though, so I gave a solution that mutates `numbers`.

Comment: I actually don't need to preserve the original list, I just created the list to give the for-loop something to iterate through.

Comment: I just want to to change the value of each of the numX_imgs so that I can call them individually later on and draw them at their correct size without needing to go through the list itself.

To clarify a little bit. Later on in the program I am going to create a function that draws the score using the images to represent the numbers. So

        if score == 0:
            "draw num0_img" in the correct size

Comment: @user3738713 - Oh, I see.  But may I ask what is wrong with having a list of images?  IMO, using numbered variables such as `num0_img`, `num1_img`, etc. is bad design...especially when you can simply use a list and have them numbered by index.  For example, `images[0]` would be the same as `num0_img`, `images[1]` would be `num1_img`, etc.

Comment: @iCodez - After messing around with it some more and using the list in my program it turns out that's what I wanted. It shortens the code and makes it easier to pull up all of the numbers later on in the program.

Thank you so much for your help?

Comment: @user3738713 - You are certainly welcome!  Please do not forget to accept my answer though by clicking the check.  Doing so lets people know that this problem is solved.